# How to ensure safe authorization in client app (ASP.NET Core WebAPI and React)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have application in ASP.NET Core WebAPI and React. I use JWT authorization. I am looking for some kind of safe authorization in specific case.

I have whole another website on this server and I call it like this in React component:

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
title="Inline Frame Example"
width="1000"
height="1000"
src="./subpages/1/index.html">
</iframe>
```

I call API method for user with JWT and get true or false value in return. Next I do something like that in React component:

```
this.state.authorized ?

<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
title="Inline Frame Example"
width="1000"
height="1000"
src="./subpages/1/index.html">
</iframe>

:

<Redirect to ='/' />
```

but I'm afraid it's a dangerous solution. I have limited possibilities for changes in the subpage

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is you're worried about. You've only shown front end code, which is not where authorization should happens. Authorization should happen in the back end, so as long as the backend is secure you should be fine.

Comment: Yes, but I have all data in frontend, in backend I have only informations about access to subpages. I am worry, that is some way for user to intefere in frontend code and ignore authorization informations from backend

Comment: How do you have the data in the front end without getting it from the back end first?

Comment: if the "protected" pages can be accessed without any kind of security token that means you have no security. Whatever you do on the frontend is meaningless. Everybody with the right URL can get in.

Comment: @Morse I thought so, but I am looking for solution in this case. Store whole subpage in backend?  I am afraid about server load, subpage loads data dynamically. Maybe pass some kind of parameter and check it in subpage to load correctly?

Comment: the subpage is already on the backend. Even if it's a static which is provided by the nginx (or whatever it is in your case) it's still a backend. Statics indeed do not usually get protected, since there is no private or sensible info there. If you do have private or sensible info in your statics, you need to protect them as well. The best way is to extract such data from the statics, and to load it dynamically. But turning the whole statics into dynamics would work too.